# getting the value of a constant in android class, Android

Tags: android, class, view, visible, invisible

I am getting a compiler error in my class for the constant "VISIBLE" that I am trying to use in the following example

```
  if((enterIP.getVisibility()).equals(VISIBLE)){
```

the compiler error is, "VISIBLE cannot be resolved to a variable"

from the Android documentation

public int getVisibility()

Added in API level 1
Returns the visibility status for this view.

Related XML Attributes
android:visibility
Returns
One of VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, or GONE.

how do I get the numerical value of VISIBLE or how can I use it in the example I showed?

Comment: use View type to call the constant VISIBLE, INVISIBLE , GONE

Comment: You are getting the compile time error because "VISIBLE"|  "INVISIBLE" | "GONE" are the constants in "View" class not in "Activity" class. To make use of constant you need to call the constant through class name "View.VISIBLE"|"View.INVISIBLE"|"View.GONE". Hope this may clear why it is compile time error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VISIBLE alone is nothing so you are getting `VISIBLE cannot be resolved to a variable`.

Just use `View.VISIBLE` to resolve it to that type.

**VISIBLE:**

```
int android.view.View.VISIBLE = 0 [0x0]

public static final int VISIBLE
```

Comment: the other error in my code is that I used .equals() for the primitive in value.   had to change to == or != when comparing to int values, because VISIBLE is an int

Answer (score 1):

use

```
if((enterIP.getVisibility()).equals(View.VISIBLE)) {

}
```

instead of

```
if((enterIP.getVisibility()).equals(VISIBLE)){

}
```

because `VISIBLE` is constant inside `View` class  or you can use any View like Button,TextView to access constants from View class like `enterIP.VISIBLE`

Answer (score 0):

VISIBLE, INVISIBLE and GONE are attributes of your enterIP View, so you would use it like this:

```
 if((enterIP.getVisibility()).equals(enterIP.VISIBLE)){
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
View.VISIBLE
```

Then may be you can solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have commented the reason why you are facing the compile time error. But if you still want to do the same has you are trying to do we can do the following.

declare the variables globally

```
public static final int INVISIBLE=View.INVISIBLE;
public static final int VISIBLE=View.VISIBLE;
public static final int GONE=View.GONE;
```

and then use you code

```
if((enterIP.getVisibility()).equals(VISIBLE)){
```

Now the error seems to be gone.

**Note**: Done this way avoid calling "View" class each and every time.

Hope this helps you.